How can I implement an alert message in React to notify users when geolocation permission has not yet been granted or denied?
I'd like to display an alert message when the user hasn't chosen to permit or deny yet. I've implemented state management for this purpose, but the message isn't showing up. I'm utilizing the navigator API. Here's my code:
const [noGeo, setNogeo] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
            if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function (position) {
                        formik.setFieldValue('latitud', position.coords.latitude);
                        formik.setFieldValue('longitud', position.coords.longitude);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.error("Error getting geolocation: ", error.message);
                    },
                    {
                        enableHighAccuracy: true,
                        timeout: 5000,
                        maximumAge: 0
                    }
                );
            } else {
                setNogeo(true);
            }
        }

       
    }, []);

return (
<>
{noGeo ? <AlertMessage />: ''}
</>
);

I'd like the Alert message component to appear before the user decides to permit or deny access to location.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [permissionStatus, setPermissionStatus] = useState('pending');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if geolocation is supported by the browser
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      alert('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
      return;
    }

    // Check permission status when component mounts
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' })
      .then(permission => {
        setPermissionStatus(permission.state);
      });

    // Subscribe to permission changes
    const permissionHandler = (permission) => {
      setPermissionStatus(permission.state);
    };
    navigator.permissions.addEventListener('change', permissionHandler);

    // Clean up subscription on component unmount
    return () => {
      navigator.permissions.removeEventListener('change', permissionHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  // Render alert message based on permission status
  const renderAlertMessage = () => {
    if (permissionStatus === 'granted') {
      return null; // Geolocation permission granted, no need to show alert
    } else if (permissionStatus === 'denied') {
      return <div>Please enable geolocation in your browser settings to use this app.</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Waiting for geolocation permission...</div>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderAlertMessage()}
      {/* Your app content here */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Try this code which will help for the alert popup

doesnt work: now I have this error: navigator.permissions.addEventListener is not a function
